# Modification of a read-only value attempted at ... line .... in a foreach loop

Tags: perl

I do not understand why the first two examples execute without any errors raised, but the third example causes problems.  What is the difference here?

I understand that `$0` and `$1` etc are read-only variables.  But why in the second example can I treat `$i` as an `lvalue`, but in the third example this treatment raising a modification of a read-only value error.  The first example is there just to show I know how to work around this error, but I would like to understand why the second and third examples work as they do.

I'm posting this question here because any of the other similar questions posted here either explicitly or implicitly used `$_`, `$0`, etc.  But I'm not doing that in my code.  I don't understand why my `$i` is not an `lvalue`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Example 1\n";
foreach my $i ( 1..5,100 )
  {
    my $j = sprintf "%04s", $i;
    print ">> $j\n";
  }

print "\nExample 2\n";
foreach my $i ( 11..15 )
  {
    $i = sprintf "%04s", $i;
    print ">> $i\n";
  }

print "\nExample 3\n";
foreach my $i ( 21..25,100 )
  {
    $i = sprintf "%04s", $i;
    print ">> $i\n";
  }
```

Comment: The problem is that the `foreach` variable is a reference into its iteration source. In the second and third cases, you're modifying the members of the source. `11..15` is an expression that produces an array `(11, 12, 13, 14, 15)`, and you are modifying that array. `$i = sprintf "%04s", $i` is internally doing `$array[0] = sprintf "%04s", $array[0]`. But `21..25,100` produces two things: A temporary array `(21, 22, 23, 24, 25)` [modifiable] and the constant `100`. And you can't modify the constant. `100 = sprintf "%04s", 100` is not legal.

Comment: You can check the little differences between `perl -MO=Concise -e '1 for 1 .. 2'` and `perl -MO=Concise -e '1 for 1, 2'`.

Comment: I don't like the linked answer which I'd previously seen.  The difference is there `$_` is being either explicitly or implicitly used.  But, I thought I had a lexically scoped variable `$i` that I thought was an lvalue.  So, it would be nice if there was an answer which addressed that difference.

Comment: @choroba Interesting, but I don't know yet how to read that.

Comment: @RaymondChen But I've got a variable `$i` there.  How is `$i` not different from a `constant`?  I thought by saying `foreach my $i` I would be working with an `lvalue`.

Comment: `foreach` aliases the elements of the list it iterates over.

Comment: @A.Ellett Your problem is that you did use `my $j` in the first loop, but then you stopped using that, and used `$i` instead. Go back to `my $j` and your problem will go away. Or better yet, don't use `sprintf` to store a temp value in a variable right before printing it, just use `printf` directly.

Comment: That `$i` looks like a variable but it isn't. It's an alias.

Comment: @TLP (1) actually the issue isn't about printing things but building keys for a hash based up an external data source and I need to fill in some of the gabs in how thoses "ID"s in the original data source were created.  I just created a MWE that boils things down to something simple that nevertheless raises the same error. (2) the first example is there to show that I **do know** how to get around the error.  I just want to understand why the error is arising.

Comment: @A.Ellett Well, the answer is given in the comments, and in the other question. The values are aliased to the for variable, no matter if `$_` or another variable is used. Consider what would have happened it you had a c-style for loop `for (my $i = 0; $i < $x; $i++)` and you tried to change the `$i` value during loop time. It's not a good idea.

Comment: @A.Ellett "_But, I thought I had a lexically scoped variable `$i` that I thought was an lvalue._"  --- ok, a good idea, but: while `$i` is indeed lexical it is also aliased to the list elements, just like `$_` is; so you're back to the linked Q-A. A summary: the `1..5,100` is set up as a list at compile time (because of the comma) with read-only values, while the range `11..15` is computed at runtime as the loop goes  (not read-only). So in the first case you don't assign to the topicalizer (so no problem), in the second you do but it isn't read only. Is that good enough?

Comment: @zdim  That actually clarified a lot.  Thank you.